# How can I check whether I am using the 2nd instance of Outlook?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption, addin-express

My question is little different here. For example, I opened two instances of Outlook. Then closed the first instance and running the other instance. Is it possible in C# to detect whether I am using the first/original instance?

I am working on an addin (VSTO) for Outlook and facing issues when the second instance is active, even though closed the first instance.

FYI, I am using Redemption, AddIn-Express, VSTO (C#).

Answer (score 1):

You will be using the one and only instance of Outlook - unlike other Office apps, it is a singleton. Check with the Task Manager - there is only one outlook.exe process running.

What you get  is a new Explorer when you, for example, right click on a folder and select "Open In New Windows". When that happens `Application.Explorers.NewExplorer` event will fire. When an inspector is closed, `Explorer.Close` event fires.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I have checked that using "if (app.Explorers.Count > 1)". This works fine when we have two instances running. But the problem that we are facing with the 2nd (duplicate instance) when the 1st (original) one is already closed.

If you say it as "explorer", is it possible to detect whether using the original or the duplicate explorer?

Comment: If the last Outlook window (be that Explorer or Inspector) is closed, Outlook will also close (even if you hold a reference to its objects). In that case, Outlook will be restarted.